# Get nth element of a vector inside a data.frame column for the whole column - R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have a `data.frame`named `ga.topPages`

```
>ga.topPages
              pagePath             pageTitle   pageviews
1     /meine-inhalte/2       Übersichtsseite        4986
2       /mein-profil/1           Mein Profil         805
3   /meine-nachrichten     Meine Nachrichten         661
4            /app.html                 Login         531
5                    /                 Login         420
```

I want to get, from column `pagePath`, the first element between "/"s. Using `strsplit` I create an aux column:

```
ga.topPages$temp1 <- strsplit(ga.topPages$pagePath,"/")
```

Column temp1 is, therefore, a vector of objects:

```
> head(ga.topPages$temp1, 1)
[[1]]
[1] ""  "meine-inhalte" "2"
```

As said, I just need to get the nth element of this vector. I can get this element individually by defining the following function (f.i., in the following example I get the second element of the first observation):

```
(function(x){ga.topPages$temp1[[x]][2]})(1)
```

I want to do it for the whole column in the data.frame. I imagine that I can do it by creating a loop, but my question is, if there is a way to do it without a loop. Sadly, I cannot get the logic to do it.

Comment: If I am correct, you just want everything that is between the "/". For eg: **meine-inhalte**. You just want this?

Comment: Yes. The only problem is that some elements of pagePath don't have two "/", like "/meine-nachrichten" or "/app.html". In this case, the logic is to get just the text string without the first "/". Even for row 5 ("/" itself) it doesn't matter if the result is an empty cell, because I will "clean" those elements in next steps.

Comment: Firstly, you should write a statement to replace all the single "/" with `""`. So row 3,4,5 will be clean. Then tackle your next problem

Comment: And how many "/" do you have maximum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** With the `stri_extract_first` from the *stringi* package, you can do:

```
library(stringi)
mydf$temp1 <- stri_extract_first(mydf$pagePath, regex='[^/]+')
```

which gives:

```
> mydf
            pagePath        pageTitle pageviews             temp1
1   /meine-inhalte/2  Übersichtsseite      4986     meine-inhalte
2     /mein-profil/1       MeinProfil       805       mein-profil
3 /meine-nachrichten MeineNachrichten       661 meine-nachrichten
4          /app.html            Login       531          app.html
5                  /            Login       420              <NA>
```

---

**Old answer:** First remove the first `"/"` with `gsub("^/","",mydf$pagePath)`, then you can use for example the `stri_split_fixed` finction from the *stingi* package to get the first element:

```
library(stringi)
mydf$temp1 <- stri_split_fixed(gsub("^/","",mydf$pagePath), "/", n=1, tokens_only=TRUE)
```

gives:

```
> mydf
            pagePath        pageTitle pageviews             temp1
1   /meine-inhalte/2  Übersichtsseite      4986     meine-inhalte
2     /mein-profil/1       MeinProfil       805       mein-profil
3 /meine-nachrichten MeineNachrichten       661 meine-nachrichten
4          /app.html            Login       531          app.html
5                  /            Login       420
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take on this:

```
vec <- c("/meine-inhalte/2", "/mein-profil/1", "/meine-nachrichten", "/app.html", "/")  
sapply(vec, function(x) ifelse(grepl("/", x), unlist(strsplit(x, "/"))[2], x), USE.NAMES=F)

[1] "meine-inhalte"     "mein-profil"       "meine-nachrichten" "app.html"          NA
```

Stating, that it's always first occurance of "/", means that it will be always second element of `strsplit()` output. All that is left to take care of - cases when there is no "/" at all.
And depending on what you intend to do with cases when there is only "/", you can replace NA with empty string afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Often `sub` alone does the job for me when I need to do string extraction or replacement

```
> sub("^/([^/]+).*", "\\1", vec)
[1] "meine-inhalte"     "mein-profil"       "meine-nachrichten" "app.html"          "/"
```

If you do complicated stuff with `sub` you might end up with quite horrible regexp patterns, but in simple cases like this I prefer to keep the code compact and not load other packages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_extract` from the stringr package with a regex pattern that detects any characters with the exclusion of a forward slash, where said pattern must be preceded by a forward slash. The regex would be `"(?<=/)[^/]*"` where `[^/]*` is anything but forward slash and `(?<=/)` specifies that it is preceded by forward slash:

```
ga.topPages <- data.frame(pagePath = c("/meine-inhalte/2", "/mein-profil/1", "/meine-nachrichten", "/app.html", "/"),
                          pageTitle = c("Übersichtsseite", "Mein Profil", "Meine Nachrichten", "Login", "Login"),
                          pageviews = c(4986, 805, 661, 531, 420)) %>% 
  mutate(new_var = str_extract(pagePath , "(?<=/)[^/]*"))
```